# What is the simplest working example of the Android NDK's module importation?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am unable to locate a working example of the Android NDK's [module importation feature](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.html). The following Android.mk files seem correct, and the inner module builds and executes without error. However, building the outer module fails with the following error messages:

> Android NDK: jni/inner/Android.mk:inner: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions
>   Android NDK: jni/inner/Android.mk:inner: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension
>   /home/caleb/dev/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-shared-library.mk:30: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

The inner, contained Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := inner
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libinner
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := inner-module.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The outer, containing Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := outer

$(call import-module,inner)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += inner

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Have you declared NDK_MODULE_PATH? If so, what's it?

Comment: NDK_MODULE_PATH is declared and set to "jni", which is the directory in which the inner module is located. If I unset NDK_MODULE_PATH, I get a different error, indicating the build system was unable to locate the inner module.

Answer (score 4):

Try placing the call to import-module at the end of your outer file. It is not a must to place it before referencing 'inner', and the NDK documentation actually advice you to place it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems with what you are doing so here is how things should look.

The inner, contained Android.mk file:

```
# save away the previous local path
INNER_SAVED_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := inner
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libinner
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := inner-module.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
# at this point LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME will have been auto
#  set to libinner.so or similar by the call to BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY

# restore previous local path
LOCAL_PATH := $(INNER_SAVED_LOCAL_PATH)
```

The outer, containing Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

$(call import-module,inner)
# at this point
#  a) we've still got the correct LOCAL_PATH as we didn't trash it in
#     the included Android.mk file
#  b) LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME is still set to libinner.so which if not
#     unset will cause BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY to complain

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# we've now got a clean slate

LOCAL_MODULE := outer

# the build system has 'remembered' the inner module
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += inner

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm not sure if this is *the* way to do it but it works for me :)