# android.mk LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not contain extensions

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android.mk

i am trying to build some of the files from `libavcodec` and `libavutil`

Following [this](https://github.com/prajnashi/ffmpeg/blob/master/Android.mk), i created Android.mk file as below :

`jni/Android.mk` contains

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

FFMPEG_TOP := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(FFMPEG_TOP)/libavutil/Android.mk
include $(FFMPEG_TOP)/libavcodec/Android.mk



LOCAL_PATH := $(FFMPEG_TOP)
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm  # remove this if you want thumb mode
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myfunc1.c myfunc2.c maincfunction.c 3rdparty1.c 3rdparty2.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += libavcodec.a libavutil.a

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

`jni/libavcodec/Android.mk` contains

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SOURCE_H264_DECODER += h264.c h264idct.c h264pred.c h264_parser.c cabac.c
SOURCE_H264_ENCODER += h264enc.c h264dspenc.c

SOURCE_HAVE_ARM = \
    arm/dsputil_arm.c        \
    arm/dsputil_arm_s.S        \
    arm/jrevdct_arm.S \
    arm/mpegvideo_arm.c        \
    arm/simple_idct_arm.S

SOURCE_HAVE_ARMV5TE = \
    arm/mpegvideo_armv5te.c \
    arm/mpegvideo_armv5te_s.S \
    arm/simple_idct_armv5te.S

SOURCE_HAVE_ARMVFP = \
    arm/dsputil_vfp.S \
    arm/float_arm_vfp.S

SOURCE_HAVE_ARMV6 = arm/simple_idct_armv6.S

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
   allcodecs.c \
   audioconvert.c \
   bitstream.c \
   bitstream_filter.c \
   dsputil.c \
   eval.c \
   faanidct.c \
   imgconvert.c \
   jrevdct.c \
   opt.c \
   options.c \
   parser.c \
   raw.c \
   resample.c \
   resample2.c \
   simple_idct.c \
   utils.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SOURCE_H263_ENCODER)                 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SOURCE_H264_DECODER)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SOURCE_HAVE_ARM)                
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SOURCE_HAVE_ARMV5TE)                
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(SOURCE_HAVE_ARMVFP)

LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                           \
    $(FFMPEG_TOP)/                         \
    $(FFMPEG_TOP)/libavutil/                \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)                            \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/arm/

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O4 -mno-thumb-interwork -mno-thumb -marm -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

`jni/libavutil/Android.mk` contains
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
   adler32.c \
   aes.c \
   avstring.c \
   base64.c \
   crc.c \
   des.c \
   fifo.c \
   intfloat_readwrite.c \
   lfg.c \
   lls.c \
   log.c \
   lzo.c \
   mathematics.c \
   md5.c \
   mem.c \
   random.c \
   random_seed.c \
   rational.c \
   rc4.c \
   sha1.c \
   tree.c \
   utils.c

LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                                 \
    $(FFMPEG_TOP)/                                \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)                 \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/arm/

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O4 -mno-thumb-interwork -mno-thumb -marm -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The problem addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783734/what-is-the-simplest-working-example-of-the-android-ndks-module-importation) is not relavant to what i am facing, though the error is similar.

The error i got is:

```
Android NDK: jni/inner/Android.mk:mylib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions
Android NDK: jni/inner/Android.mk:mylib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension
```

Please help!!
[So often i am meeting headless problems!!]

Answer (score 12):

You need to ensure that you call `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` after you include the make files which build your static libs.  The auto generation of the module file name only works if that variable is empty, and your previous make file includes end up defining it when you call `$include ($BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libavcodec LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME += libavutil` instead of `LOCAL_SRC_FILES += libavcodec.a libavutil.a` in your `jni/Android.mk`.